# before_create method in model not working when a user is created - Rails4

Tags: ruby-on-rails

- i am unsure why my code is not working - your help would be much appreciated
- what i want to do is: when a user is created the user is assigned to the role "Client" and the group "Client Group"

---

### question: i am unsure why my `before_create` action is not working. could one kindly advise me on this?

i get the error message:

```
NoMethodError - undefined method `name' for nil:NilClass:
```

i find that strange as when i check my category in my terminal all is seems fine
[image]

> user.rb

```
user belongs_to :category_role
user belongs_to :category_managementgroup

before_create :assign_user_to_role_and_group

def assign_user_to_role_and_group
    self.category_role.name == "Client"
    self.category_managementgroup.name == "Client Group"
  end
```

> category_role.rb

```
has_many :users
```

> category_managementgroup.rb

```
has_many :users
```

> seed.rb

```
CategoryRole.delete_all
cr01 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Admin')
cr02 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Primary Admin')
cr03 = CategoryRole.create!(name:'Client')

CategoryManagementgroup.delete_all
cmr01 = CategoryManagementgroup.create!(name:'Administration Group')
cmr02 = CategoryManagementgroup.create!(name:'Client Group')
cmr03 = CategoryManagementgroup.create!(name:'Management Group')
```

> schema

```
create_table "users", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "email",                         default: "", null: false
    t.integer  "category_role_id"
    t.integer  "category_managementgroup_id"
  end

create_table "category_roles", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end

create_table "category_managementgroups", force: :cascade do |t|
    t.string   "name"
    t.datetime "created_at", null: false
    t.datetime "updated_at", null: false
  end
```

Comment: Are you getting any exception? If I understand this right, `self.category_role` and `self.category_managementgroup` will be null in your `before_create`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you probably meant something like this:

```
def assign_user_to_role_and_group
  self.category_role = CategoryRole.where(name: 'Client').first
  self.category_managementgroup = CategoryManagementgroup.where(name: 'Client Group').first
end
```

That is, actually *assign* role and group, to actual *objects* of respective classes.

Comment: sergio you are awesome!!! - works perfectly, i would not have figured it out as simple as it may have seem - thank you!!!